I am getting 98% to 100% accuracy in my logistic regression classifier on different seeds. Is it supposed to happen(mainly concerned about 100% acc)
My data split:
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df.drop('id', axis=1, inplace=True)
X = df.drop('classification', axis=1)
y = df['classification']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, 
    y, 
    test_size = 0.30, 
    random_state =0 
)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
output:(280, 23) (120, 23) (280,) (120,)

AND MY ML MODEL:
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```


Welcome to Cross Validated! What is your statistics question? For instance, are you wondering if this performance is too good to be true? My question back to you in response to that is, what is your class ratio? If you have 99% of observations belonging to one category, I would view that 98% accuracy rather differently that I would if you have equal representation of each group. $//$ A logistic regression does not do any classification, no matter what the predict method returns. It is possible to evaluate classifiers, sure, but do note that a logistic regression does no classification.

thanks for the answer Dave. And my class ratio is 40:60. I am also getting same result for decision trees too.

What is wrong with 100% accuracy? Without knowing what you analyse we can not make any judgement about it and answer it. Just plot your classes as function of the classifier (which will be some linear combination of the X matrix columns) and see whether it makes sense or not.

I have 400 observations and 24 parameters. It is a model to detect if someone has kidney disease

Of those 400, how many have kidney disease? Also, please put your answers to our comments  in the question itself. Right now, the question has almost no information.

It seems like your test set is of size 120. If your error is roughly 1% then this is not a very large test set to accurately describe the error. Potentially you can use a semi-parametric approach. What is the distribution of the predictor? I can imagine that you can approximate it with a normal distribution and use that to make a prediction about the accuracy.

What sort of accuracy are you aiming for? Are you comparing different methods and is it critical to accurately compare them whether the one has 99% accuracy and the other 99.1% accuracy?

This approach violates too many statistical principles to list.  And logistic regression is not a classifier, it is a probability model.  You have miscast a problem of estimating tendencies (probabilities) of getting disease with a classification problem.  See here for details.

There are many reasons why you can get 100% accuracy. I don't see any obvious problems in the code. In terms of data, it is quite possible you just have an easy problem, meaning, it is quite easy for the classifier to recognize the classifications.
Or, more likely, that you are "leaking" some data on the classification in the features. For example, there may be some other column that also (implicitly) lists the classification. Just another copy of the same column, or perhaps the arrival time in the hospital that is trivially related to the classification.
Another very likely mistake is that all classifications are 0, or all of them are 1. This is called unbalanced data. Or it can be a mistake in the data transformation.
Without having seen your data, it's hard to figure out what's going on. You can try manually selecting a few columns, see if it matches your intuition. Some unrelated columns should lead to an accuracy of ~20% (assuming 20% of observations are ones or zeros).
